# Draw Completely White Texture in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, draw, game-engine

What I want to do is draw a texture like normal in OpenGL, but completely white. I tried doing `glColor3f(2.f, 2.f, 2.f)` but that doesn't work. I just want to draw the shape of a certain texture but without color and just white, so I'm trying to draw a texture but white...

To clarify the desired result: I want the RGB part of all colors sampled from the texture to be white, while the alpha value is the one sampled from the texture. So if the value in the texture is (R, G, B, A), I want the sampled color to be (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, A).

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. If you want to render the whole shape white, why would you want to use a texture in the first place? And what do you mean by "shape of a texture"? Textures are essentially just images, and their shape is always rectangular.

Comment: I mean, if a pixel is 127 transparent then draw a white pixel of 127 transparency, if a pixel is 255 transparent then draw a white pixel of 255 transparency etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn the color from the texture white, but still use the alpha value sampled from the texture, you can use:

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_ADD);
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

With the `GL_ADD` texture env mode, the incoming fragment color (which the second call above sets to white) will be added to the color sampled from the texture to obtain the output color. Since output colors are clamped to the range [0.0, 1.0], the color components from the texture do not matter, since they will be added to 1.0 before the result is clamped to 1.0. So the RGB color part of the output will always be white.

The less obvious part is what happens to the alpha value. According to the spec, the alpha value from the incoming fragment and the alpha value sampled from the texture are **multiplied** for the `GL_ADD` texture env mode. With the fragment alpha set to 1.0, this means that the resulting value is the alpha value from the texture, which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use a pixel shader and set each fragment's color to white.

Comment: Are you trying to render a texture from a file that is loaded into memory such as reading from a tga, png or bmp file; or are you just trying to add a white "material" to your object?

Comment: (...continued) When working with 2D & 3D graphics there is a difference between a texture and a material. Textures are loaded into memory from a file and is mapped to your rendering object, where a material can be applied to that same object. Lets say you have a 3D Box rendered with a texture of a crate that maps to it: if your material is white then the texture will display as is. If you add color to the material it will shade that texture to the color in the material.

Comment: (...continued) The only thing with a material there are different settings such as ambient, diffuse, specular, emissive, etc. that has the be kept track of since with OpenGL you have to create your own light sources if you are working with older versions of OpenGL that doesn't involve Shaders. You also have to keep track of and manage normal too when working with lighting.

Comment: *Shaders are annoying*.  +1 for fun but you really need to stop using vanilla GL 1.1/2.0 and start to use these techniques.  There's more boilerplate for sure but things have moved on since 1994.  Modern techniques are so much more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a 1x1 white RGBA bitmap in code.

```
GLubyte texData[] = { 255, 255, 255, 255 };
```

Copy data to texture.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1, 1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texData);
```

Comment: I'm not trying to make a white square, "I mean, if a pixel is 127 transparent then draw a white pixel of 127 transparency, if a pixel is 255 transparent then draw a white pixel of 255 transparency etc" based on the image I want to make white.